# Android, how to define a defaut style for a custom View

Tags: android, styles, android-custom-view

My custom view class:

```
class SearchBox : FrameLayout {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet?
    ) : this(context, attrs, R.attr.searchBoxStyle)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, @AttrRes defStyleAttr: Int) : this(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr,
        R.style.SearchBoxStyle
    )

    constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet?,
        @AttrRes defStyleAttr: Int,
        @StyleRes defStyleRes: Int
    ) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {

        inflate(context, R.layout.search_box, this)

        val a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.SearchBox, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)

        a.recycle()
    }
}
```

Declaration of a style:

```
<style name="SearchBoxStyle" parent="">
    <item name="background">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Styleable (is empty for now, i would use platform attributes, like "background"):

```
<declare-styleable name="SearchBox">
</declare-styleable>
```

**The problem**
"background" property is never set.

How can I define a simple default Style for a custom View?

### UPDATE

```
    <declare-styleable name="SearchBox">
        <attr name="background" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
```

```
constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet?,
        @AttrRes defStyleAttr: Int,
        @StyleRes defStyleRes: Int
    ) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {

        inflate(context, R.layout.search_box, this)

        val a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.SearchBox, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
        val background = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.SearchBox_background)
        background?.apply { setBackground(this) }

        a.recycle()
    }
```

Is this the right way?

I hope there is a way to do it even without redefining all the attributes of the platform and then applying them by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself, platform attributes works, but they start with "android:...".

So, using `"android:background"` it works.